# HEALTHCHECK in Dockerfile

Tags: docker, containers

Is having `HEALTHCHECK NONE` in Dockerfile same as not specifying `HEALTHCHECK` in Dockerfile ?

I can't seem to find any documentation about this. Would appreciate any pointers around this

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

Comment: `HEALTHCHECK NONE (disable any healthcheck inherited from the base image)`

Comment: @TalRofe Happy to accept your response. Can you post it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Docker reference documentation: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#healthcheck

`HEALTHCHECK NONE (disable any healthcheck inherited from the base image)`

So the answer in **no** - it is not the same. If you code the line in your `Dockerfile` - you also disable (if present) any healthchecks provided from your base image.

So imagine you built your image on top of other image (suppose `node alpine`), then- if `node alpine` image would have `HEALTHCHECK ...` configured in its `Dockerfile`, then doing `HEALTHCHECK NONE` in **your dockerfile** - disables the origin healthcheck.